# Registering new mouse buttons with events in KDE

Tags: kde, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

Is there a file or something where I can register the mouse events to do something? I'm using KDE.

For example, in Windows, pressing Win + ArrowKeys nicely aligns the windows, I am looking for the file where I need to register this event.

Also, how do I see the output of a KeyEvent?

Comment: This depends on your desktop environment or window manager: unlike Windows, unix gives you a (wide) choice there. Which one are you using? If you don't know, what distribution are you using?

Comment: I am using KDE and would like to register the hotkeys of my choice for the new mouse buttons or anything else.

Is there a script file for this or should I dig into the actual code?

Comment: Ok, I voted to reopen now that you've provided the missing piece of information. There's a GUI for that. Do you want to define a key or a mouse event — your question shifts between the two? The interface is usually the same anyway.

Comment: @Giles Appreciated! I actually wanted to do both, identify the key input from the new keys from the Mouse and assign an event. 

Similarly apply the keys for another mouse event.